# how to get the complete destination IP addres (x.x.x.x/x) netstat command?

Tags: linux, networking, ip

Below is the output of the netstat command with `-n` & `-r` options in which the destination field shows compacted address (127.1/16). I wanted to know that is there any way or options available to netstat command to display entire Destination IP (127.1.0.0/16) rather than (127.1/16) ?

```
#netstat -r -n
Destination        Gateway            Flags     Refs     Use    Mtu    Interface
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH        110   296172    33212  lo0
127.1/16           link#7             UC          2        0        -  vlan10
```

Answer (score 0):

But the command is not showing 127.1.0.0/8, it's showing 127.1/16, which means the whole 127.1.x.x range.

Read up on netmasks: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork#IPv4_subnetting

And experiment with them here, to get a better understanding: http://jodies.de/ipcalc

Comment: Thks..!! It was typo in the question corrected now.!.. The destination field should display 127.1.0.0/16 or 127.1.0.0 instead of 127.1/16. plz suggest.

Comment: I tried the same command >netstat -r -n it gives the complete destination address.

Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.220.6.1     10.220.7.182     20
          5.5.5.0    255.255.255.0      10.220.6.46     10.220.7.182     21
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider alternatives to just using netstat. "netstat -r" gives the same output as "route". You could also try "ip route show", or "ip route show dev " if you want to see routes going via a particular device/interface. Your may also be interested the output returned by "routel".